# Adding a text field to a contextMenu

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to add a `TextField` to a `.contextMenu`, something like

```
.contextMenu {
  TextField("type the code", text: $text)
}
```

I did that and the `TextField` shows but it is read only.

Is it possible to make the `TextField` able to accept typing? That would be amazing.

Comment: Have you seen any other UI with a `TextField` in a context menu? I haven't, neither do I think it may be good for UX. I'm not sure it's possible

Comment: The app has a demo mode. That will appear just for our developers.

Comment: I'd assume the best thing then is to either have the app settings in the real Settings app on the device, or have a `NavigationLink` which then just goes to a `Form` with rows for text fields, toggles, etc. Won't look brilliant, but for demo in-house I think that's fine